# Count Distinct with Answer side by side instead of underneath

Tags: postgresql, count, distinct

Here is my query:

```
SELECT substring(date,1,10), count(distinct id),
CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM table
WHERE (date >= '2015-09-01')
GROUP BY substring(date,1,10), CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
ORDER BY substring(date,1,10)
```

This is my result:

```
substring     count     case
2015-09-01     20472      0
2015-09-01         7      1
2015-09-02     20465      0
2015-09-02       470      1
```

What I want it to look like is this:

```
substring     count    count
2015-09-01    20472        7
2015-09-02    20465      470
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With PostgreSQL 9.4 or newer, we can filter directly an aggregate with the new `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT substring(date,1,10),
  count(distinct id),
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE name IS NOT NULL)
FROM table
WHERE (date >= '2015-09-01')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use case in count to get columns for some condition (name IS NOT NULL), like this:

```
SELECT substring(date,1,10)
, count(distinct CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN id ELSE null END ) AS count1
, count(distinct CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN null ELSE id END ) AS count2
FROM table
WHERE (date >= '2015-09-01')
GROUP BY substring(date,1,10)
ORDER BY substring(date,1,10)
```

you can also use subquery to create columns:

```
SELECT dt, Count(id1) count1, Count(distinct id2) count2
FROM (    
  SELECT distinct substring(date,1,10) AS dt
  , CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN id ELSE null END AS id1
  , CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN null ELSE id END AS id2,
  FROM table
  WHERE (date >= '2015-09-01')) d
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The first query, made me put in a GROUP BY clause:  GROUP BY substring(date,1,10), name

Comment: It ended up giving me 3 entries for each date instead of just one also

Comment: Nevermind...fixed it... I'll post the one I used below:

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT substring(date,1,10)
, count(distinct CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN id ELSE null END ) AS count1
, count(distinct CASE WHEN name IS NOT NULL THEN null ELSE id END ) AS count2
FROM event
WHERE (date >= '2015-09-01')
GROUP BY substring(date,1,10)
ORDER BY substring(date,1,10)
```

This gave me an answer like this: (which is exactly what I wanted so thank you so much)

```
substring    count1   count2
2015-09-01        7    20472
2015-09-02      470    20465
```

Comment: If there are `id` duplicates, the `count2` above will count them only once, whereas in the question, you seem to want to count the non-null `name`, independantly of whether there are `id` duplicates. That's not the same thing.